# Move a const/function in to a custom hook / re-usable piece of code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-hooks

In my functional component / page I've got a const/function that I pass error messages to, that then updates a couple of useState records and logs the error to the console. It looks like this:

```
const catchError = (e:any, message:string) => {
    //throw new Error(e)
    setMessage(message);
    setLoading(false);
    console.error(e);
};
```

I'd like to move this code to a hook(?) / helper file that will allow me to import it into any other component. This would mean I can use one centralised piece of code rather than writing the same code in multiple places and avoid the associated issues.

So, I've created a new `catchError.tsx` file with the following content:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const [ message, setMessage ] = useState("idle");
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);

export const catchError = (e:any, message:string) => {
    //throw new Error(e)
    setMessage(message);
    setLoading(false);
    console.error(e);
};
```

However, when I render this I get the following compile error:

> Failed to compile
>
> src/hooks/catchError.tsx   Line 3:33:  React Hook "useState" cannot be
> called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React
> function component or a custom React Hook function
> react-hooks/rules-of-hooks   Line 4:33:  React Hook "useState" cannot
> be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React
> function component or a custom React Hook function
> react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

This is new territory for me.

(PS: I'm quite new to React / TypeScript and would welcome any corrections in my terminology).

Comment: the file name `catchError.tsx` and the function name should be prefixed by `use` like this `useCatchError` in order for react to recognize it as a custom hook. Also, you have to move your useStates inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse hook logic (like useState) you can write your own custom hooks.

I believe something like so could work, though I am not completely sure how this would be used without more context.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function useCatchError() {
  const [ message, setMessage ] = useState("idle");
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);

  const catchError = (e:any, message:string) => {
    //throw new Error(e)
    setMessage(message);
    setLoading(false);
    console.error(e);
  };

  return { catchError, message, loading };
}
```

And be used like

```
export function Foo() {
  const {catchError, message, loading} = useCatchError();
  
  try {
    bar();
  } catch (e) {
    catchError(e, e.message);
  }

  return (
    <div>
       {message ? `Error: ${message}` : loading ? "Loading" : "Foo"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

More on custom hooks in the React Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to return anything, I just need to pass in the 2 values (e and message). Then use `catchError` from any other page/component by importing it. If I import useCatchError as per your code and import as `import { catchError } from '../hooks/useCatchError';` I get the error `Module '"../hooks/useCatchError"' has no exported member 'catchError'.` Any suggestions?

Comment: P.s. My catchError code is literally whhat I posted in my question. I just need to be able to reuse that code across multiple components/pages without manually adding that code in full on every page. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to return the message and loading value you can swap out `return { catchError, message, loading };` for `return catchError` and then you will be able to get that function with `const catchError = useCatchError();`.

However you have to call the hook in your render method for every component, there is no getting around that.